# Let $A\subset\Omega$ and $\mathcal{B}_{A} = \{B\cap A:B\in\mathcal{B}\}$. Show that $\mathcal{B}_{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $A$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a nonempty set and $\mathcal{B}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$. Let $A\subset\Omega$ and $\mathcal{B}_{A} = \{B\cap A:B\in\mathcal{B}\}$. Show that $\mathcal{B}_{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $A$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

To begin with, notice that $A\in\mathcal{B}_{A}$. Since $\Omega\in\mathcal{B}$, we conclude that $A = \Omega\cap A\in\mathcal{B}_{A}$.

Let us suppose that $S_{1},S_{2},\ldots, \in\mathcal{B}_{A}$. Then one has that $S_{i} = B_{i}\cap A$ for some $B_{i}\in\mathcal{B}$, where $i\geq 1$. Consequently,
\begin{align*}
S = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}S_{i} = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}(B_{j}\cap A) = \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}B_{j}\right)\cap A = B\cap A \Rightarrow S\in\mathcal{B}_{A}
\end{align*}

Could someone help me to prove that $\mathcal{B}_{A}$ is closed under complementation?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I assume that you have not identified the complement of some $S = B\cap A$ correctly. Since we are looking at subsets of $A$, the complement of $S$ is $A\setminus S$. Perhaps you might want to try to visualize the complement of $S$ with a Venn-diagram to identify how to write it as $C\cap A$ for some $C\in\mathcal{B}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S =A\cap B\in \mathcal B_A$ where $B \in \mathcal B$  then complement of $S$ in $A$ is $A\cap S^{c}$ and $S^{c} \in \mathcal B$ so $S^{c} \in \mathcal B_A$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $S\in \mathcal{B_A}$. Then there is some $B\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $S=B\cap A$. Since $\mathcal{B}$ is a sigma-algebra we have $\Omega\setminus B\in\mathcal{B}$. So now if we can show that $A\setminus S=(\Omega\setminus B)\cap A$ then we are done. This is just a two sided inclusion.

If $x\in (\Omega\setminus B)\cap A$ then in particular $x\in A$, and since $x\notin B$ we also have $x\notin S$. So $x\in A\setminus S$.

On the other hand, if $x\in A\setminus S$ then $x\in A$, and in particular $x\in\Omega$. Also, $x\notin B$. (because if $x$ was in $B$ then we would get $x\in B\cap A=S$, a contradiction). So $x\in (\Omega\setminus B)\cap A$.